# Store XML data in DOM parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, domparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify XML data in Dom parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666140/how-to-modify-xml-data-in-dom-parser)

I am new working in Java and XMl DOm parser. I had a requirment like read the xml data and store it inform of column and rows type. this is a sample code

```
ki need to read this XMl file and store it in the above format:



 Expected Output"
      swetha,Eunis,swetha,10000
        john,MAdiv,Jo,200000
```

But i am getting spaces between them, for 4 tags 4 spaces are coming
Output of the below Code:

```
 swetha,Eunis,swetha,10000



        john,MAdiv,Jo,200000
```

Java Code:

```
 NodeList nl= doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for(int i=1;i< nl.getLength();i++)
            {
                Element section = (Element) nl.item(i);
                Node title = section.getFirstChild();
                    while (title != null && title.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                            {
                                title = title.getNextSibling();
                                if (title != null)
                                {
                                    String first=title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                                    if(first!=null)
                                    {
                                        title = title.getNextSibling();
                                        System.out.print(first + ",");
                                        br.write(first + ",");
                                    }
                                } 

                            }//WHILE
                    br.write("/n");
                    System.out.print("\n");
              }
```

I am not able to find how to remove spces between the lines.