# How to read Data Dynamically From XML File

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to read data from xml file Dynamically.I had  70 tag names to read and store the data in form of row's. by looking the above code I can read data as i want but how can i write all the tagnames manually using getTagValue(*,*), how can I retrieve data dynamically into getTagValue(*,*). I posted some code which I have tried in the above link

```
public class ParseXML {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("data/Hotel.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

           Node nNode = nList.item(i);
           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

              String firstname=getTagValue("firstname", eElement);
              String lastName=getTagValue("lastname", eElement);
             String nickname=getTagValue("nickname", eElement);
             String salary=getTagValue("salary", eElement);
             System.out.println(firstname+" ," + lastName+" ," + nickname+" ," + salary);
           }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
  }

}
```

[How to modify XML data in Dom parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666140/how-to-modify-xml-data-in-dom-parser)

Comment: its not clear what you want to say. You have already written tagnames in getTagValue()

Comment: Ya int the above code i wrote only 4 tag names, but if i had 150 tag names then how to loop all the tag names with single step

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to generate the tag names dynamically into private static String `getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement)` `"stag"` instead of declaring manually `"firstName","lastName","nickName","Salary"` into

```
String firstname=getTagValue("firstname", eElement);           
String lastName=getTagValue("lastname", eElement);             
String nickname=getTagValue("nickname", eElement);              
String salary=getTagValue("salary", eElement);
```

Hear i declared 4 TagNames, if i have 150 tag Names its really Hard Code to write the 150 TagNames manually.is there way to generate "stag" dynamilcally

Comment: see this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: I refered the above link before, i need to work only with XMl DOm parser